# Mono: Bug 702532 - DuplexClientBase Channel Initialization Broken

Tags: mono

Is there any way to work around [this bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=702532), and get `DuplexClientBase` properly work?

Comment: I believe I've seen a fix related to this recently (ie. last couple of months), but I'm not sure.  Are you getting this problem with Mono 3.0.x ?

Comment: @MartinBaulig yes, I do.